# Android - custom Layout Inflater

Tags: android, layout-inflater

is there any way how to override default layoutInflater to be able to dynamically create layouts depending on my will, while taking data for XML structure from database?

Hmyzak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [LayoutInflater.setFactory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#setFactory%28android.view.LayoutInflater.Factory%29) and [LayoutInflater.setFilter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#setFilter%28android.view.LayoutInflater.Filter%29) methods.